# Iterate over XML nodes and send emails in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, xml-parsing

I'm getting an XML to my stored procedure and I need to iterate over it and send emails according to the XML.

I have another stored procedure just for sending the email:

```
MailingSystem..SP_SendEmail 
               @Cc = N'', -- nvarchar(500)
               @Bcc = N'', -- nvarchar(500)
               @FromEMailAddress = N'', -- nvarchar(500)
               @ReplyToEMailAddress = N'', -- nvarchar(500)
               @Subject = N'', -- nvarchar(500)
               @EmailRecipient = N'', -- nvarchar(500)
               @ContentType = N'', -- nvarchar(50)
               @Content = N'', -- nvarchar(max)
```

Here is the structure of the XML:

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML =          
        '<GenericXML>
             <GenericEmailsNotification>
                 <EmailMessage>
                     <From>John@Google.com</From>
                     <Recipients>Naomi@Yahoo.com</Recipients>
                     <CC>Tania@HotMail.com</CC>
                     <Subject>Follow The Sun </Subject>
                     <Body>Breathe, breathe in the air. Set your intentions.Dream with care. </Body>
                 </EmailMessage>
                 <EmailMessage>
                     <From>ron@Google.com</From>
                     <Recipients>Fake@Yahoo.com</Recipients>
                     <Subject>Second Email is best</Subject>
                     <Body>Second Email body...</Body>
                 </EmailMessage>
             </GenericEmailsNotification>
         </GenericXML>'
```

I want to loop over each `EmailMessage` node and extract the data related to this node/email (Subject, From, Recipients, Body and etc) and send it to the stored procedure that in charge of sending the mail.

Each XML can have multiple emails to send (if its not clear until now..)

How can I do it ? there is any way to loop over the XML elements ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parse `XML` and use cursor:

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML =          
'<GenericXML>
  <GenericEmailsNotification>
    <EmailMessage>
      <From>John@Google.com</From>
      <Recipients>Naomi@Yahoo.com</Recipients>
      <CC>Tania@HotMail.com</CC>
      <Subject>Follow The Sun </Subject>
      <Body>Breathe,breathe in the air.Set your intentions.Dream with care</Body>
    </EmailMessage>
    <EmailMessage>
      <From>ron@Google.com</From>
      <Recipients>Fake@Yahoo.com</Recipients>
      <Subject>Second Email is best</Subject>
      <Body>Second Email body...</Body>
    </EmailMessage>
  </GenericEmailsNotification>
</GenericXML>' ;
```

Query:

```
SELECT  [from]       = s.c.value('(./From)[1]', 'nvarchar(250)')
       ,[Recipients] = s.c.value('(./Recipients)[1]', 'nvarchar(250)')
       ,[CC]         = s.c.value('(./CC)[1]', 'nvarchar(250)')
       ,[Subject]    = s.c.value('(./Subject)[1]', 'nvarchar(250)')
       ,[body]       = s.c.value('(./Body)[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)')
INTO #Emails       
FROM @XMLData.nodes('/GenericXML/GenericEmailsNotification/EmailMessage')
     AS s(c);

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT [from],[Recipients],[CC],[Subject],[body] FROM #Emails;

DECLARE @from       NVARCHAR(250),
        @recipients NVARCHAR(250),
        @cc         NVARCHAR(250),
        @subject    NVARCHAR(250),
        @body       NVARCHAR(MAX);

OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @from, @recipients, @cc, @subject, @body;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   -- send email, pass variables to SP call, handle `NULL` with `ISNULL` if needed
   -- EXEC MailingSystem..SP_SendEmail @Subject = @subject, ...

   SELECT 'Send email in cursor loop:', @from, @recipients, @cc, @subject, @body;

   FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @from, @recipients, @cc, @subject, @body;
END

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/FNYKM34277)**</kbd>

Comment: One thing extra that i needed is at the very end of that code is "Drop Table #Emails".
Otherwise after the first run it tell me that an object #Emails already exist.
Other than that, two thumbs up!